# Converts tags/keys from site.tags into array in jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm new to Jekyll and Ruby in general. I'm trying to turn a list of tags into an array. I've tried these code below, but it doesn't work.

```
{{ site.tags.key }}
```

Is it Liquid limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I found these solutions:

```
{{ site.posts | map: 'tags' | uniq }}
```

It gathers lists of tags from posts.